# Receiving a C# Enum in JavaScript and passing it to a model via Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my code, I need to receive a string, convert it into a C# enum, and pass the enum to my model. The code is within a for-loop (not shown).

```
 var thisDwm = document.getElementById("dwm_" + i).value;       
            var urlDwm = "/KnowledgeTransfer/GetDailyWeeklyMonthlyEnum";
            var response
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: urlDwm,
                data: { 'caseFromJS': thisDwm },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (thisResponse) {
                    response = thisResponse;
                }
            })
            model.MainResponsibilities[i].DailyWeeklyMonthly = response;
```

Currently the ajax hits my C# controller and returns the correct enum. But when I look at the JavaScript breakpoints, "response" remains undefined and is not set. How do I set the response to a C# enum object that I can pass to my model? Is there some parsing that needs to happen? It seems like I am not receiving anything from the controller at all.

One thing that doesn't help is that type, data, contentType, success, and thisResponse all show as "having a reference error  is undefined" in Chrome. Yet the Ajax still works, at least in other places, even though these other methods also show this error.

Thank you for your assistance.

Edit: below is my controller method:

```
public ObjectModel.Enums.DailyWeeklyMonthly GetDailyWeeklyMonthlyEnum(string caseFromJS)
        {
            switch (caseFromJS){

                case "Daily":
                    return ObjectModel.Enums.DailyWeeklyMonthly.Daily;
                case "Weekly":
                   return ObjectModel.Enums.DailyWeeklyMonthly.Weekly;
                case "Monthly":
                   return ObjectModel.Enums.DailyWeeklyMonthly.Monthly;
                case "Yearly":
                    return ObjectModel.Enums.DailyWeeklyMonthly.Yearly;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("problem with dailyWeeklyMonthly in KnowledgeTransferController");
```

Comment: You might look into the [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of your `switch` case. That way if the enum changes, you don't have to change the method:  `GetDailyWeeklyMonthlyEnum(string caseFromJS) { DailyWeeklyMonthly result; if (!Enum.TryParse(caseFromJS, true, out result)) throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown enum value: {caseFromJS}"); return result; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you shared, you will get  ***response is not defined*** error if you are trying to use the `response` variable before it is defined. In the code snippet you shared, you are initializing it only inside the `success`  callback method of your ajax call.

Remember, ajax is **asynchronous**. When JavaScript framework executes this line `model.MainResponsibilities[i].DailyWeeklyMonthly = response;`, which is outside the success callback scope, The ajax call might be still executing/waiting for the response from the server, this means nothing has been set to `response`, which means the variable `response` is not initialized!

Access the response for your ajax call only inside the `success` or `done` callback.

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: urlDwm,
         data: { 'caseFromJS': thisDwm },
         contentType: 'application/json',
         success: function (thisResponse) {
              // safe to use thisResponse in this callback method scope
              console.log(thisResponse);

              // Assuming model.MainResponsibilities[i] exist
              model.MainResponsibilities[i].DailyWeeklyMonthly = thisResponse;
         }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I put all my code within the success function. I will need to study promises to find a better way to control logic in a non-linear way.